# Why is there a delay in the hiding of an element by my script?

Tags: jquery, fade

I am trying to make some kind of tab div.
I have got 4 buttons and by default I am showing the first div.
Now I am trying to hide the div that is open when I click another one.
Tried different ideas but none seem to work. I've seperated the buttons and the content into 2 divs:

My HTML snippet:

```
<div class="button wrapper">
   <button class="btn btn-1" rel="btn-1" href="">Horeca</button>
   <button class="btn btn-2" rel="btn-2" href="">Winkel</button>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="mycontent-1" style="display: block;">
      <h1>Horeca</h1>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, ratione, ullam?
         Aspernatur deserunt ducimus ex explicabo iste maiores molestiae odio pariatur rem vero.
         Distinctio dolor error placeat quos sunt voluptatum!
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="mycontent-2" style="display: none;">
     <h1>Winkel</h1>
     <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, ratione, ullam?
        Aspernatur deserunt ducimus ex explicabo iste maiores molestiae odio pariatur rem vero.
        Distinctio dolor error placeat quos sunt voluptatum!
     </p>
</div>
```

jquery Snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-1").click(function(){
      $(".mycontent-1").fadeToggle(function(){
         $(this).siblings().hide();
            });
      });
    $(".btn-2").click(function(){
      $(".mycontent-2").fadeToggle(function(){
         $(this).siblings().hide();
            });
      });
});
```

For some kind of reason the div that is suppose to hide stays in the DOM for a few miliseconds before it disappears. I want it to smoothly pass into the next div. So when the first div finish fading I want to start the fade in of content of the clicked button. Should I do some kind of success function to make this work?

Comment: You code says when I am done, hide these elements. So the elements do not get hidden until that code is done running If you want them to hide, you need to move that line out of the done callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're complicating it with the `fadeToggle` event operating on siblings. Try this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbratch/8075k6cx/4/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-1").click(function() {
      $(".mycontent-1").siblings().hide();
      $(".mycontent-1").fadeIn();
    });
    $(".btn-2").click(function() {
      $(".mycontent-2").siblings().hide();
      $(".mycontent-2").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

So here for each button click, we're hiding the siblings and fading in the desired `div`.

You can also be a little more concise and use just one event that uses selector wildcards and checks the number of the button and operates on the correct div number ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbratch/8075k6cx/8/)). This will work with multiple buttons/divs that follow your naming conventions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // on click of a button with "rel" attribute that starts with "btn-"
    $("[rel^=btn-]").click(function() {
      var n = $(this).attr("rel").split("-")[1]  // get the number
      $(`.mycontent-${n}`).siblings().hide();
      $(`.mycontent-${n}`).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all mate, you are missing a div close tag to close the seconds div with my `class="mycontent-2"`.
Second all you need is to hide the div, don't worry about its content because they are already included in it and will hide with it.
Third, you need to hide all other elements before attempt to show the other one.
In general try this in your jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-1").click(function(){
        $(".mycontent-2").hide("slow", function(){
            $(".mycontent-1").show();
        });
    });
    $(".btn-2").click(function(){
    $(".mycontent-1").hide("slow", function(){
            $(".mycontent-2").show();
        });
    });
});
```